# Changing useEffect to custom hook resets useReducer state to initial state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm creating a feature for a component where I need to perform a particular step when a property's value changes from defined to undefined. To facilitate this I've create a custom hook I named `usePropertyHistory` that works similar to the `useEffect` hook; the main differences are that my hook only accepts a single dependency, the callback has previous and current value parameters, and it performs a deep equal on the value instead of just an `Object.is` comparison. The problem I'm having is the `useReducer` state within the component gets reset to its initial value when I use this custom hook versus when I use React's `useEffect` hook. Below is a condensed code listing that works:

```js
const MyComponent = ({ value }: ComponentProps) => {
  const initialState: DropDownBaseState = {
    isMultiSelect: allowMultiSelect,
    isListOpen: false,
    isPassedValue: false,
  };

  const [state, dispatcher] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (value) {
      dispatcher({
        type: DropDownBaseActionType.SetPassedValue,
        passedValue: value,
      });
    }
  }, [value]);

  // when the dispatcher function above is called this effect fires after the state change happens
  useEffect(() => {
    if (state.selectedValue && state.selectedValue.length > 0 && textBoxRef.current) {
      textBoxRef.current.setInnerText(state.selectedValue[0].text);
    } else if (state.selectedValue && state.selectedValue?.length < 1) {
      setShowPlaceholder(true);
    } else if (!state.selectedValue) {
      setShowPlaceholder(true);
    }
  }, [state.selectedValue]);

};
```

And now in this code listing the only thing different is the custom hook is used to call the dispatcher function:

```js
const MyComponent = ({ value }: ComponentProps) => {
  const initialState: DropDownBaseState = {
    isMultiSelect: allowMultiSelect,
    isListOpen: false,
    isPassedValue: false,
  };

  const [state, dispatcher] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

  usePropertyHistory((previousValue, currentValue) => {
    if (currentValue) {
      dispatcher({
        type: DropDownBaseActionType.SetPassedValue,
        passedValue: currentValue,
      });
    } else if (previousValue && !currentValue) {
      // in the test being run this section never gets called
      dispatcher({
        type: DropDownBaseActionType.ClearSelectedValue,
      });
    }
  }, value);

  // when the dispatcher function above is called this effect never fires...the
  // state change does happen on the next render, but when the following render
  // happens the state is set back to its initial value
  useEffect(() => {
    if (state.selectedValue && state.selectedValue.length > 0 && textBoxRef.current) {
      textBoxRef.current.setInnerText(state.selectedValue[0].text);
    } else if (state.selectedValue && state.selectedValue?.length < 1) {
      setShowPlaceholder(true);
    } else if (!state.selectedValue) {
      setShowPlaceholder(true);
    }
  }, [state.selectedValue]);

};
```

Below is the posting of the `usePropertyHistory` hook:

```js
const usePropertyHistory = <T>(callback: (previous: T | undefined, current: T | undefined) => void, property: T) => {
  const previousProperty = useRef<T>();
  if (!deepEqual(previousProperty.current, property)) {
    callback(previousProperty.current, property);
    previousProperty.current = property;
  }
}
```

I have performed a good amount of testing and I have discovered the following:

1. This issue has nothing to do with React Strict Mode.
2. Even in the second code listing the only reducer action called is `SetPassedValue`, so that is not what's causing the reset of the reducer state.
3. Wrapping the initial state in a `useMemo` doesn't fix the issue, not saying I thought it would but I did give it a try.

For some reason the `useEffect` in the first listing works while calling the same code in the custom hook does not. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Please include the code of `usePropertyHistory`.

Comment: OK @OriDrori I've added the code listing

Comment: The `else if (previousValue && !currentValue)` doesn't exist in the `useEffect` based code, and it clears the dropdown. Add this code to the `useEffect`, and it would probably would behave in the same way.

Comment: Where is `value` coming from?

Comment: Yes the `else if` doesn't exist in the first listing, but it is never called in the test I was running. Secondly `value` is coming from a property passed into the component.